# How can a user buy tokens from the Web?

Tags: ether, dapp-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I know Token holder can send Token to other user by using Mist Or MyEthereumWallet but How it is possible by any web application?

is there any specific ethereum api's by which we can buy sell token and could check balance for running ICO Sale? 
Or 
there will be need of any Dapp developed by truffle framework ?

Kindly help me out it is too confusing for me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running your own ICO, you would have to build a Dapp using web3 (with or without Truffle) that acts as a front-end for your token sale.
Given that each crowdsale contract is different, you would have to build such interface yourself, depending on what the smart contract looks like, there is no "API".

Comment: Thanks @pabloruiz
One more question . do i need to install the full main node on ethereum on server where Dapp is deployed?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can deploy it using Infura

Comment: You don't need anything at all in your server. Is the user, using your Dapp who must have a node or light client. Your Dapp with connect to 127.0.0.1, that means, the user's localhost, his client or node.

Comment: @FernandoGarcia Interesting ! you mean without installing any ethereum node on server we could use it by Meta mask or some thing?

Comment: @UmarAbbas If you create the Dapp, you don't need to install anything. Your server could be an apache that just servers your HTML/JS page. Then, most probably you will use web3.js, that connects to localhost. The  user will load your website, and connect to localhost (his node), so it is the user who has to install the node or use a light client or something like Metamask. Even more, if you upload your static web page to something like SWARM, you don't even need a server at all